# Flask logging from dict config

Tags: python, logging, flask, flask-restful

I have a flask API and I want to log all ocurrences about it into a log file. I have a dict config then I started a app.logger and I imported dict config, but nothing change in a log.file during requests.

This is the dict config:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "handlers": {
    "fileHandler": {
      "class": "logging.FileHandler",
      "formatter": "myFormatter",
      "filename": "/opt/foo/foo.log"
    }
  },
  "loggers": {
    "foo": {
      "handlers": [
        "fileHandler"
      ],
      "level": "INFO"
    }
  },
  "formatters": {
    "myFormatter": {
      "format": "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my main code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.logger
    logging.config.dictConfig(json.load(open('config/config_log.json')))
    app.logger_name = 'foo'
    app.run(threaded=True, host='0.0.0.0', debug=False)
```

Request log call:

```
@app.route('/api/foo', methods=['POST'])
def run():
    app.logger.info("Test")
```